# Why does JHipster say that my entity is not declared?

Tags: jhipster

In file1.jdl I have entity X definition and import-jdl generated it correctly, and can see it in .jhipster/X.json

In file2.jdl I have this relationship:

```
relationship OneToMany{
    X{subordinateX} to X{superiorX}
}
```

When I try to import-jdl on file2.jdl it gives me this error:

> Error while parsing applications and entities from the JDL Error: In the relationship between X and X, X and X are not declared.

Is this an issue or I did something wrong?

Thx

Comment: did you found any solution to this ? i have the same problem 
thanks

Comment: Problem was that entity and relationship were declared in 2 separate files. Use one file for everything and it should work. As far as performance is concerned, like @Marziou suggests, I don't know. In the end, my solution took another path. I'm using JHipster 6.8.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i thought i had similar to your problem .... , my case is that i have a project generated with jhipster and already deployed and in production mode , today i have to add a relationship to an existing table and i couldn't do it from jhipster cmd  !! any idea about that ? i want to only add relationship to an existing tables .

Comment: Post your JDL file and error log so it can be examined

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is due to the fact that you define a bidirectional self relationship, it seems you're modeling a tree or a hierarchy of some kind.

If you were doing it in SQL, I suspect that this would lead to performance problems when traversing the tree. If you search for "How to represent a tree in SQL" you will find that it's a classic problem and depending on which database engine you use, you may even find a specific structure to manage it. You can search also for "How to represent a tree in JPA".

Have you tried simplifying it like "X{subordinateX} to X" to avoid being bidirectional?

So, it's probably a bug in JHipster but it could be hard to fix because it has many implications in UI for instance. Feel free to report it on github, maybe someone else will propose a fix.

As a workaround, you could try to create an external entity to materialize this hierarchical relationship (a kind of join table in SQL) with only 2 columns subordinate and superior.

Comment: Hey , i have the same problem , i just want to know if this bug has been fixed on a latest version or not ?  any idea ?